# SQL for select id and childrens for example in ( 1,2 ) and then select courses for this 2 categories

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have my 2 tables like this and I want to select course for categories table where id, i.e 1 , also with courses that has parent 1 as category.

I try something like:

```
SELECT id,category,( (SELECT id FROM courses WHERE id = 1 OR parent = 1) AS selection) FROM courses 
WHERE category IN selection;
```

But is not a right syntax, and also I would say I miss puttting into string comma separated to do something like that.

table categories

```
+----+--------+------+
| id | parent | path |
+----+--------+------+
|  1 |      0 | /1   |
|  2 |      1 | /1/2 |
+----+--------+------+
```

table courses

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | category | shortname |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 |        0 | MB2.9.8   |
|  2 |        2 | 1 c       |
|  3 |        2 | 2 c       |
|  4 |        1 | c 3       |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

Which means I would have  this when I just send category id = 1 , because categories.parent on id "2" has "1" as parent too so selection of courses for 1 and 2 categories

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | category | shortname |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  2 |        2 | 1 c       |
|  3 |        2 | 2 c       |
|  4 |        1 | c 3       |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a join

```
select CO.*
from Courses CO
inner join Categories CA
    on CA.Category = CO.Id
    or CA.Category = CO.Parent
where CA.ID = 1
or CA.Parent = 1
```

or an EXISTS:

```
select CO.*
from Courses CO
where exists (
    select Id 
    from Category CA
    where (CA.Parent = CO.Category
    or CA.Id = CO.Category)
    and (CA.ID = 1
    or CA.Parent = 1)
    )
```

Comment: sometimes guys , you make feel stupid  ... and I thank you @JohnHC for that. Cheers!